# Combine columns from different tables to make one table Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have three different tables. I want to select different columns from each of the tables and create one table based on some filters. Have a look at the following dax expression:

```
FILTER(DISTINCT(SELECTCOLUMNS(Test_Table,"site_key",[site_key],"is_active",[is_active])),[is_active]=TRUE&&[dbsource]=="DB2")
```

As you can see, I've selected olumns from `Test_Table`.

Firstly, How can I add columns from the other two tables?

Secondly, please note that these tables are related so I've created a relationship between them based on relevant IDs.

Will I have to create a natural join in DAX as well?

Comment: I'd recommend [SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](https://dax.guide/summarizecolumns/) in general for this sort of thing.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Can you place it in the dax expression to explain?

Comment: Maybe if you explain what other columns you'd like to include and how they're related to `Test_Table`.

Comment: @AlexisOlson another table test_table_2 having a relationship on site_key with Test_Table. Test_Table_2 contans columns by the name of industry_group, country and state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, [SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-summarizecolumns/) can probably get you what you're looking for. It might look something like this in your case:

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    Test_Table[site_key],
    Test_Table_2[industry_group],
    Test_Table_2[country],
    Test_Table_2[state],
    FILTER ( Test_Table, [is_active] = TRUE && [dbsource] = "DB2" )
)
```